# How to automatically start and stop an influxdata process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, influxdb

I've recently set up my first influxdb using

https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-c-and-influxdb/

This tutorial. I got the application to work and changed the program to fit my needs. I'm aware that you can start the process by typing "dotnet run" in CMD and stop it by pressing ctrl + c in CMD.

But how could you automatically start and terminate the process via c# code?

I'd like the process to run when called by another Programm and then be terminated after 24 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be reduced to how to start and schedule a process to shut down.

[Timer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) and
[ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=net-5.0#examples) can be used.

In my demo, `open(button)` will open the `.txt` file in the `path`.

`close(button)` will start a 5s countdown to close the `notepad` program.

You can change it according to your needs.

The .net 4.8 framework winform is used here.

Of course, you can also use the console application to complete this.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartApp(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Start the process
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ArrayFolderPath">Need to open the path of the process folder, multiple paths are separated by ','; eg:d:\test,e:\temp</param>
        private void StartApp(string ArrayFolderPath)
        {
            string[] foldersNamePath = ArrayFolderPath.Split(',');
            foreach (string folderNamePath in foldersNamePath)
            {
                GetFolderApp(folderNamePath);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Recursively traverse all exe files in the folder, this method can be further extended to other suffix files
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="folderNamePath">Folder path</param>
        private void GetFolderApp(string folderNamePath)
        {
            string[] foldersPath = Directory.GetDirectories(folderNamePath);
            foreach (string folderPath in foldersPath)
            {
                GetFolderApp(folderPath);
            }

            string[] filesPath = Directory.GetFiles(folderNamePath);
            foreach (string filePath in filesPath)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

                //Open the file with the suffix .txt
                if (fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".txt"))
                {
                    Process.Start(filePath);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetTimer();
        }
        private static void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CloseApp("Notepad");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close the application
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ArrayProcessName">The application names are separated by ','</param>
        private static void CloseApp(string ArrayProcessName)
        {
            string[] processName = ArrayProcessName.Split(',');
            foreach (string appName in processName)
            {
                Process[] localByNameApp = Process.GetProcessesByName(appName);//Get all processes with program name
                if (localByNameApp.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var app in localByNameApp)
                    {
                        if (!app.HasExited)
                        {
                            app.Kill();//close the process
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]